# flexbox parent div have no height in ios 10 safari but not the case in ios 11 safari

Tags: html, ios, css, safari

```
<div class="column">
<div class="trainer">
<span>
  hihi
</span>
</div>
</div>

.column {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: red;
}

.trainer {
  display:flex;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex: 25%;
}
```

[jsfiddle code sample](https://jsfiddle.net/8j3hemt6/)

you can try the above link.
In firefox and ios 11 safari, the parent div background color is shown,
while in ios 10 safari, I cannot see the parent div background color.

So how can I fix the zero height of parent problem in ios 10 safari?

PS. I found that if I change the `25%` to `25px`, the red background appear in ios 10 safari. Does it mean ios 10 safari doesn't support `flex-basis` in percentage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Safari 6.1+ , you can use `-webkit-flex-basis` property.

```css
.column {
  display:-webkit-box;
  display:-ms-flexbox;
  display:flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: red;
}

.trainer {
  display:-webkit-box;
  display:-ms-flexbox;
  display:flex;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
  justify-content: space-around;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 25%;
  -webkit-flex-basis: 25%;
  flex-basis: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <div class="trainer">
    <span>hihi</span>
  </div>
</div>
```